# Monitoring context switches in Linux

Tags: c, linux, profiler, context-switch, oprofile

Is there any way to determine whenever a context switch takes place without the use of profilers? I have written a C program to monitor the time taken for different processes in a program to finish execution. I want to show the process/thread context switching as well. The time at which the switch takes place and from `prev_id -> curr_id`. These 3 informations would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can observe voluntary_ctxt_switches and nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches values from the /proc/self/status file.